# Вывести списочную форму

Tags: python

Для неотрицательного целого числа X списочная форма –— это массив его цифр слева направо. К примеру, для 1231 списочная форма будет [1,2,3,1]. На вход подается количество цифр числа Х, списочная форма неотрицательного числа Х и неотрицательное число K. Числа К и Х не превосходят 10000.

Нужно вернуть списочную форму числа X + K.

Формат ввода

В первой строке — длина списочной формы числа X. На следующей строке — сама списочная форма с цифрами записанными через пробел.

В последней строке записано число K.

Формат вывода

Выведите списочную форму числа X+K.

Пример 1

```
Ввод                                      Вывод
4                                         1 2 3 4
1 2 0 0
34
```

Не понимаю как нужно делать эту задачу, помогите плиз. Вот то что я попробовал но это не то.

```
n = int(input())

array = []

for i in input().split():

   array.append(int(i))

k, j = input().split()

k, j = int(k), int(j)

array = array[:j - 1] + [k]

ret = str(array[0])

for i in range(1, len(array)):

   ret = ret + ' ' + str(array[i])

print(ret)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно так:

```
input()
X = int(input().replace(' ', ''))
K = int(input())
print(' '.join(str(X+K)))
# print(list(str(X+K)))
```

Или еще так:

```
input()
X = list(map(int, input().split()))
K = list(map(int, input()))
var = len(K) - len(X)
if var > 0:
    X = [0]*var+X
elif var < 0:
    K = [0]*var+K
res = [sum(el) for el in zip(K, X)]
print(res)
```

Answer (score 2):

Вот самый простой пример:

```
x = int(input())
k = int(input())
res = x+k
res = list(str(res))
print(res)
```

Сначала получаем 2 числа тип `int`, то есть, целочисленные. Далее складываем их и переводим результат в строку, после чего разбиваем строку на список

Вот пример, если первое число означает кол-во первых цифр из суммы

```
b = int(input())
x = int(input())
k = int(input())
res = x+k
res = list(str(res))
res = res[:b]
print(res)
```

Comment: Только понять не могу зачем надо получать первое число???

Comment: Наверно учебные задачи остались со времен Паскаля, а язык изменился)

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME, вероятно, что так)

Comment: @DGDays Обратите внимание - второе число (из трёх) вводится через пробелы, ваши примеры работать не будут.

Comment: @CrazyElf, я списал это на опечатку автора Извинюсь

Answer (score 1):

Однострочник, извините:

```
input(), print(' '.join(str(sum(map(int, (''.join(input().split()), input()))))));
```

Comment: input(), print(*str(int(input()[::2])+int(input())))

Comment: @Danis Да, так ещё короче. Нет предела совершенству ))  `;` кстати нужна, если вводить код в `ipython`, а то лишний вывод будет. Хотя мне ненравится привязка к конкретным позициям в слайсе, всё же `split` поуниверсальней будет